# How to run node js on web/hosting/cpanel

Tags: node.js, web, hosting, cpanel

is there a way to run a script on website / cpanel / hosting?

So I have a script that run with node js

Normally I run this code on my mac terminal but I want to run my code on my website. Is it possible?

What should I do? Because I do not expert with PHP, just know a litle bit about NODE JS

How to move my script (node js) to my website and run it